# Tikz-Place a rectangle in specific angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, arc, angle

I am trying to place a rectangle on top of an imaginary circle of certain radius, whose center lies in the middle of another rectangle. What I've tried so far is the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  % Incident Beam
  \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (2,0);
  % Target : Boron + Au --- The center of the imaginary circle is in the center of these rectangles
  \draw[gray!30,fill=gray!30] (6,1) rectangle (6.5,-1);
  \draw[gray!70,fill=gray!70] (6.5,1) rectangle (8.5,-1);
  % Scattering Chamber - The imaginary circle
  %\draw[thick,red,->,dashed] ([shift=(-120:5cm)]7.25,0) arc (0:100:-1cm);
  %\draw[dashed, gray!50] (7.25,0) circle (7cm);
  % Telescopes --- I want to place this rectangle on 170 degrees on top of the imaginary circle
  \draw[black!70, fill=black!70, rotate=30] (2,-2) rectangle (2.5, -2.5); 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

How to place this black rectangle, on a certain angle on top of the dashed circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the center of the imaginare circle is on `(7.25,0)` and the radius of the circle is 7cm you can insert a rotated rectangular node at `(7.25,0)+(170:7)`:

```
\path(7.25,0)+(170:7)
  node[
    fill=black!70,
    minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=1cm,% rectangle
    rotate=80 % 170°-90°=80°
  ]{};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Incident Beam
  \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (2,0);
  % Target : Boron + Au --- The center of the imaginary circle is in the center of these rectangles
  \draw[gray!30,fill=gray!30] (6,1) rectangle (6.5,-1);
  \draw[gray!70,fill=gray!70] (6.5,1) rectangle (8.5,-1);
  % Scattering Chamber - The imaginary circle
  %\draw[thick,red,->,dashed] ([shift=(-120:5cm)]7.25,0) arc (0:100:-1cm);
  \draw[dashed, red] (7.25,0)coordinate(M) circle [radius=7cm];
  % Telescopes --- I want to place this rectangle on 170 degrees on top of the imaginary circle
  \path(7.25,0)+(170:7)
    node[fill=black!70,
    minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=1cm,% rectangle
    rotate=80 % 170°-90°=80°
    ]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What I want to do is draw a rectangle instead of a square. How is that possible inside a `node`?

Comment: I used `minimum width` and `minimum height` to create a rectangle instead of a square!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use nodes,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,dotted,minimum size=3cm,circle] (a) {};
\node[fill,minimum size=2mm,rotate=55,inner sep=0] at (a.140) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another idea: use a sloped node for the filled square. This way, you don't have to specify the angle to rotate that square, it will be automatically computed to be aligned with the radius of the circle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    my square/.style={
       fill=orange!70, 
       minimum size=2mm, 
       pos=1, 
       sloped
    }
  }

  \draw [dotted] (0,0) circle(1.5cm);
  \foreach \angle in {0,30,...,360}
    \foreach \distance in {0.9,1.2,1.5}
      \path (0,0) -- (\angle:\distance) 
         node[my square] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

### Update

Answering the additional question in the comment, a rectangle can be drawn giving the minimum width and height of the node. It can be useful, however, to leave the width as a parameter with a default value:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    my rectangle/.style={
       fill=orange!70, 
       minimum width=#1,   % The width is a parameter
       minimum height=2mm, 
       pos=1, 
       sloped
    },
    my rectangle/.default = 4mm,   % Width when not specified
  }

  \draw [dotted] (0,0) circle(1.5cm);

  % Some rectangles with default width
  \foreach \angle in {0,30,...,330}
     \path (0,0) -- (\angle:1.5) node[my rectangle] {};

  % Other rectangles with given width (and different color)
  \foreach \angle in {0,90,...,330}
     \path (0,0) -- (\angle:1.5) node[my rectangle=7mm, red] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result2]

Comment: I really like your approach! What if I want to create rectangles and not squares? I tried adding `maximum size=20mm` but it wasn't valid...

Comment: Instead I used `minimum width` and `minimum height` which is valid!

Comment: @Thanos, see my updated answer